# Basic Javascript Animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation

Very basic practice animation here:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

**JS**

```
div = document.getElementById("div")

div.onmouseover = move();

function move() {
    cHeight = div.style.height;

    while (cHeight < 300) {
        div.style.height = (cHeight + 10) + "px";
        setTimeout (move, 20);
    }
}
```

When I load the page (it's still a local file) it fails to load, and I get the Chrome "aw snap, page failed to load" error page. Which is weird, because as I said, it's still local. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got into an infinite loop!
This happens because you never update cHeight and because you combine recursive with iterative.

```
function move() {

    var cHeightStr = div.style.height.substr(-2);
    var cHeight = cHeightStr.substr(0, cHeightStr.length - 2);

    if (cHeight < 300) {
        cHeight += 10;
        div.style.height = cHeight + "px";
        setTimeout (move, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! Now it loads, but it executes immediately upon loading (and it takes a while to load)...

Comment: @Tommay I updated my answer as I did not quite fix the infinite loop, now it should be okay

Answer (score 1):

You actually should not use the while loop at all.

```
function move() {
  var cHeight = div.style.height;

  if ( cHeight < 300 ) {
    div.style.height = (cHeight + 10) + "px";
    setTimeout(move, 20); //This way the height only changes every 20ms
  }
}
```

In your code you never increment `cHeight` -> infinite loop

Comment: Yup, This is Right approach, +1. I haven't tested it yet, But using  `Timeout` you can control speed of animation.. Right way to achieve task.

Answer (score 0):

The style.height property will only be set if you set it yourself. Instead try div.clientHeight or div.offsetHeight. OffsetHeight is the same but includes padding, border and margin.

You also have some other issues in your code. You are invoking the move function immediately, rather than just assigning it as a handler, and your animation code itself is a bit broken - you don't need the while loop and the timeout.

I wrote a snippet that probably does something similar to what you wanted:

```html
<div id="div" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById("div")

div.onmouseover = move;

function move() {
    if(div.offsetHeight < 300) {
        div.style.height = (div.offsetHeight + 10) + "px";
        setTimeout(move, 20);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This worked, but after it had gone down to 300 px, if you moused over it again, it bumped down by like 10 px PAST 300 px... not sure why.

Comment: Just needed to move the height assignment inside the if statement. Fixed now.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, div.style.height shouldn't be used to measure the position.

Answer (score -1):

Okay theres a few bad things going on here, you don't want a while loop as it will move through all the positions before giving the browser a chance to render any of the changes and it never actually exits the loop...

Also the other examples on this page use div.style.height, which starts as a blank string. Primarily its an instruction for overriding the document style via JS. So it will only return a value you have previously set in JS, not the actual position of the div.

```
function move() {
    var cHeight = div.offsetTop; //this returns the current calculated top offset from the container

    if(cHeight < 300) { // if we're under 300 then update position
        div.style.height = (cHeight + 10) + "px";
        setTimeout (move, 20); //wait for next frame then update position again
    }
}
```